# OpenGL yoyo program troubles

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm having trouble getting my yoyo program to work; I have a growing and shrinking string to go along with the yoyo moving and spinning, but I've got the string moving along with the yoyo. I need to have the string staying stationary while the yoyo spins up and down.I have to have the string and yoyo's movements allocated onto one button as well. Mind helping me with my code? (also please excuse the lackluster yoyo; I wanted to finish the programming before designing it)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <math.h>

void firstDisplay();
void secondDisplay();
void movement();
void init();
void drawButton();
void handleButton(int button, int state, int x, int y);

const int Width=720;
const int Height = 480;

static float PI = 3.14159;
static float radius = 25;
static float INC= (PI/30);
static GLfloat spin = 0.0;
static GLfloat deltaz = .001;
static GLfloat deltax = 0.0;
static GLfloat deltay = 0.0;

//######################################################### Main #########################################################
void main(int argc, char** argv)

{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(Width,Height);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);

    glutCreateWindow("Yoyo");

    glutDisplayFunc(firstDisplay);
    glutMouseFunc(handleButton);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();

    return;
}
//######################################################### Draw Button #########################################################
void drawButton()
{
glBegin(GL_POLYGON); 
float theta;
    for (theta = 0.0; theta <= 2 * PI; theta += INC)
    {
        glColor3f(1,0,1);
        glVertex2f(40 + radius * cos(theta), 40 + radius*sin(theta));
    }
glEnd();
}
//######################################################### Second Display #########################################################
void secondDisplay()
{
float theta;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBegin(GL_POLYGON); //Here is the yoyo
    for (theta = 0.0; theta <= 2 * PI; theta += INC)
    {
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        float radius1 = 75;
        glVertex2f(360 + radius1 * cos(theta), 80 + radius1*sin(theta));
    }
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON); //Here is the yoyo design
    for (theta = 0.0; theta <= 2 * PI; theta += INC)
    {
        glColor3f(0,1,1);
        float radius1 = 55;
        glVertex2f(350 + radius1 * cos(theta), 90 + radius1*sin(theta));
    }
glEnd();

glFlush();

return;
}
//######################################################### First Display #########################################################
void firstDisplay()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

float theta;
glBegin(GL_POLYGON); //Here is the yoyo
    for (theta = 0.0; theta <= 2 * PI; theta += INC)
    {
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        float radius1 = 75;
        glVertex2f(360 + radius1 * cos(theta), 80 + radius1*sin(theta));
    }
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON); //Here is the yoyo
    for (theta = 0.0; theta <= 2 * PI; theta += INC)
    {
        glColor3f(0,1,1);
        float radius1 = 55;
        glVertex2f(350 + radius1 * cos(theta), 90 + radius1*sin(theta));
    }
glEnd();

drawButton();
glutSwapBuffers();
glFlush();
return;
}
//######################################################### Draw String #########################################################
void draw_string()
{ 
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3f(363, 8.25 - deltay, 0.0);
glVertex3f(357, 8.25 - deltay, 0);
glVertex3f(357, 6, 0);
glVertex3f(363, 6, 0);
glEnd();
}
//######################################################### Button Controls #########################################################
void handleButton(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    static int index =-1;

    if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
    {
        if(y>= 10 && y<= 100)
        {
            if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
            {
                glutIdleFunc(movement);
            }
            if (state == GLUT_UP)
            {
                glutIdleFunc(NULL);
            }
        }

        glutSwapBuffers();
    }
}
//######################################################### Yoyo Movement #########################################################
void movement()
{
    static int goingup = 0;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

if(goingup==1)
{
    deltay -= 6;

    if(deltay <= 0)
    {
        goingup = 0;
    }

    spin = spin -5;
    if(spin < 360)
    {
        spin = spin + 360;
    }
}
if(goingup == 0)
{
    deltay += 6;

    if (deltay >= 315)
    {
        goingup = 1;
    }

    spin = spin +5;
    if(spin < 360)
    {
        spin = spin + 360;
    }
}

glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(360+deltax, 80+deltay, 0.0);
glRotatef(spin,0.0,0.0,1.0);
glTranslatef(-360,-80, 0.0);
secondDisplay();
draw_string();
glPopMatrix();
drawButton();
glutSwapBuffers();
}

//######################################################### Init #########################################################
void init()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0,Width,Height,0);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I went separated the draw_string() and seconddisplay() functions within the movement function like so:

```
}

glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(360+deltax, 80+deltay, 0.0);
glRotatef(spin,0.0,0.0,1.0);
glTranslatef(-360,-80, 0.0);
secondDisplay();
glPopMatrix();
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(360+deltax, 80+deltay, 0.0);
glRotatef(0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
glTranslatef(-360,-80, 0.0);
draw_string();
glPopMatrix();
drawButton();
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

I removed the spin from draw_string()'s glRotatef.